# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SslStream'

Tags: azure-functions, sslstream, objectdisposedexception

We have an service bus triggered Azure function which makes a call to an http triggered Azure function and from times to times we are experiencing the error below,

> The operation was canceled. The read operation failed, see inner
> exception. Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SslStream'.

Azure application insights mentions as Failed method the **Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine+d__0`1.MoveNext**

We do use Polly to setup the following retry policy

```
HttpPolicyExtensions
                // Handle HttpRequestExceptions, 408 and 5xx status codes
                .HandleTransientHttpError()
                // Handle 404 not found
                .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                // Handle 401 Unauthorized
                .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                // What to do if any of the above erros occur:
                // Retry 3 times, each time wait 1,2 and 4 seconds before retrying.

                .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                    policyDetails.RetriesCount, 
                    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(policyDetails.TimeoutInSeconds, retryAttempt)),
                    onRetry: (outcome, timespan, retryAttempt, context) =>
                    {
                        policyDetails.logger.LogError(outcome.Exception, "An exception occurred on retry {RetryAttempt} for {PolicyKey}", retryAttempt, context.PolicyKey);
                    });
```

Moreover on startup we setup the http client  with the following code

```
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<IEmailSenderFunctionService, EmailSenderFunctionService>(c =>
            {
                // Base settings
                c.SetBaseSettings(baseUrl: httpOptions.Email.BaseUrl);

                // Function App Key
                c.SetApiKey(headerName: "x-functions-key", apiKey: httpOptions.Email.Token);
            }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(serviceProvider =>
            {
                var memoryCache = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
                var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Startup>>();

                httpPolicy.logger = logger;

                return ClientCertificateClientConfigurator.ConfigureHandlerForHttpClient(
                    logger,
                    memoryCache,
                    clientCertificateClientOptions
                    );
            }).AddPolicyHandler(PolicyHandler.WaitAndRetry(httpPolicy));
```

EmailSenderFunctionService contains simple methods to call the http trigger functions.

Call Stack

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsyncCore>d__53.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync>d__48.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithRetryAsync>d__47.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler+<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=3.1.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine+<ImplementationAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext (Polly, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8a3ffc3f8f825cc)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Polly.AsyncPolicy`1+<ExecuteAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Polly, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8a3ffc3f8f825cc)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly, Version=3.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler+<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=3.1.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__70.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at CNS.EmailSender.Client.EmailSenderFunctionService+<SendEmailMessageAsync>d__2.MoveNext (CNS.EmailSender.Client, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at CNS.MessageSender.Facades.MessagesFacade+<SendEmailMessageNotificationAsync>d__23.MoveNext (CNS.MessageSender, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\CNS.MessageSender\Facades\MessagesFacade.cs:482)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at CNS.MessageSender.Facades.MessagesFacade+<ProcessChannelAsync>d__19.MoveNext (CNS.MessageSender, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\CNS.MessageSender\Facades\MessagesFacade.cs:298)
Inner exception System.IO.IOException handled at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsyncCore>d__53.MoveNext:
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream+<ReadAsyncInternal>d__214`1.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<FillAsync>d__87.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync>d__84.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsyncCore>d__53.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.ObjectDisposedException handled at System.Net.Security.SslStream+<ReadAsyncInternal>d__214`1.MoveNext:
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckThrow (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckOldKeyDecryptedData (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.HandleQueuedCallback (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream+<ReadAsyncInternal>d__214`1.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

Does anyone else have a similar error before or any thoughts why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if the below findings helps to:**

Here is the [GitHub Open Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/986) recorded where the error belongs to Azure .NET SDK and the Azure Storage Versions.

As said that, this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/17527) would be fixed in the next Azure.Core release in the beginning of February 2021. You can use steps from [GitHub-Azure-sdk-net-blob-azure-core-changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/CHANGELOG.md#added-2) as a temporary work-around and follow the above references to track the bug fix.

Also, Refer [Azure function httpclient ObjectDisposedException Cannot access a disposed object SslStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661473/azure-function-httpclient-objectdisposedexception-cannot-access-a-disposed-objec)